# Почему возникает ошибка: "AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'format'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

ошибка AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'format'

```
print ("Первое число")
first = int( input())
print ("действие (+ - * /)")
choise = str( input()) 
print("второе число")
second = int( input())
if choise == "+":
    print( {0} + {1} .format(first, second))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет так, т.к. [str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) -- метод строки:

```
print("{0} + {1}".format(first, second))
```

А `{1}` это литерал для объявления множества (`set`). Попробуйте, например `print(type({1}))`

---

**PS.**

`{  }` -- это двойственный литерал, одновременно используемый для множества (`set`) и словарей (`dict`), например:

```
print({1})  # Множество
print({'a': 1, 'b': 2})  # Словарь
```

**PPS.**

Начиная с `python 3.6` можно использовать `f-string`:

```
print(f"{first} + {second}")
```

Comment: возможно я не верно изъяснился, но скобки убирают суть.
если записать по другому
print (first + second) только хочу записать через .format

Comment: @user341928, чтобы был результат? Тогда, лучше так: `print(f"{first} + {second} = {first + second}")`. Если через `format`, то: `print("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(first, second, first + second))`, т.к. `format` задает символы-заменители, куда значение, переданное в `format` попадет

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо поставить кавычки вокруг `{0} + {1}`

```
print('{0} + {1}'.format(first, second))
```

Либо воспользоваться f-строкой:

```
print( f'{first} + {second}')
```